# Swiper arrow could not be displayed over the container width

Tags: css, reactjs, swiper.js

[Arrows could not be shown over the width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5tix.png)

```
<Swiper 
                    slidesPerView={5}
                    spaceBetween={20} 
                    pagination={{ 
                        clickable: true, 
                    }} 
                    navigation={{
                        prevEl: navigationPrevRef.current,
                        nextEl: navigationNextRef.current
                    }}

                    onSwiper={(swiper) => {
                        // Delay execution for the refs to be defined
                        setTimeout(() => {
                            // Override prevEl & nextEl now that refs are defined
                            swiper.params.navigation.prevEl = navigationPrevRef.current
                            swiper.params.navigation.nextEl = navigationNextRef.current
                    
                            // Re-init navigation
                            swiper.navigation.destroy()
                            swiper.navigation.init()
                            swiper.navigation.update()
                        })
                    }}
 
                    breakpoints={{
                        640: {
                            slidesPerView: 2,
                            spaceBetween: 20,
                        },
                        768: {
                            slidesPerView: 4,
                            spaceBetween: 40,
                        },
                        1024: {
                            slidesPerView: 5,
                            spaceBetween: 50,
                        },
                    }}
                    modules={[Pagination, Navigation]}
                    className='category-slider'
                >
                    <SwiperSlide>
                        <div className="category-card">
                            <img src="https://clicon-html.netlify.app/image/product/product-14.png" alt="" className='category-image' />
                            <h6 className="category-text">TV & Homes</h6>
                        </div>
                    </SwiperSlide>
                    <SwiperSlide>
                        <div className="category-card">
                            <img src="https://clicon-html.netlify.app/image/product/product-12.png" alt="" className='category-image' />
                            <h6 className="category-text">Accessories</h6>
                        </div>
                    </SwiperSlide>
                    <SwiperSlide>
                        <div className="category-card">
                            <img src="https://clicon-html.netlify.app/image/product/product-9.png" alt="" className='category-image' />
                            <h6 className="category-text">Computer & Laptop</h6>
                        </div>
                    </SwiperSlide>
                  
                   
                    <button className="slick-arrow-carousel button-prev" ref={navigationPrevRef}>
                        <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path d="M20.25 12H3.75" stroke="white" strokeWidth="1.5" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round"></path>
                            <path d="M10.5 5.25L3.75 12L10.5 18.75" stroke="white" strokeWidth="1.5" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round"></path>
                        </svg>
                    </button>
                    <button className="slick-arrow-carousel button-next" ref={navigationNextRef}>
                        <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path d="M3.75 12H20.25" stroke="white" strokeWidth="1.5" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round"></path>
                            <path d="M13.5 5.25L20.25 12L13.5 18.75" stroke="white" strokeWidth="1.5" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round"></path>
                        </svg>
                    </button>
            
                </Swiper>
```

**styles.css**

```
.category-slider{
    position: relative;    
}

.swiper-pagination{
    display: none!important;
}


.slick-arrow-carousel{ 
    position: absolute!important;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%); 
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-width: 48px;
    max-width: 48px;
    min-height: 48px;
    max-height: 48px;
    border-radius: 500px;
    display: flex!important;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: var(--bs-primary-500);
    z-index: 99999;
}
.swiper-button-prev, .swiper-button-next{
    display: none!important;
}
.button-prev{
    position: absolute;
    left: -20px;     
}
.button-next{
    position: absolute;
    right: -20px;
}
```

In the swiper carousel, I am expecting the custom swiper buttons should be displayed over the width of the container when I set the `z-index: 99999` but even how I modified it could not be displayed correctly? May I ask how can I have the arrow directions to be displayed with full width instead of only be displayed in the container?

I have difficulties in Swiper Carousel properties and may want to look for suggested solutions

Comment: Such a slider needs to set `overflow: hidden` on the container element, and `z-index` on any descendants can't do anything about that. See if the suggestion from https://stackoverflow.com/a/72020974/1427878 is a workable alternative for you.

Comment: So for which class property I should use ```overflow: hidden```?

Comment: The buttons need to be taken out of the swiper container.

Comment: After I took out from the swiper container the direction buttons still could not be displayed as full width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to replicate the same issue in my react application and I have used swiper version 11.0.7 for this. Please check updated code below:-

```
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
import { Navigation } from 'swiper/modules';
import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/navigation';
import 'swiper/css/pagination';
import './index.css'; // Assuming you have your styles in a separate CSS file

const SwiperCarousel = () => {
    return (
      <div className='category-slider'>       
        <Swiper
          modules={[Navigation]}
          onSwiper={(swiper) => console.log(swiper)}
          onSlideChange={() => console.log('slide change')}
          spaceBetween={25}
          slidesPerView={5}
          navigation={{
            nextEl: '.review-swiper-button-next',
            prevEl: '.review-swiper-button-prev',
          }}
        >
            <SwiperSlide>
                <div className="category-card">
                    <img src="https://clicon-html.netlify.app/image/product/product-14.png" alt="" className='category-image' />
                    <h6 className="category-text">TV & Homes</h6>
                </div>
            </SwiperSlide>
            <SwiperSlide>
                <div className="category-card">
                    <img src="https://clicon-html.netlify.app/image/product/product-12.png" alt="" className='category-image' />
                    <h6 className="category-text">Accessories</h6>
                </div>
            </SwiperSlide>
            <SwiperSlide>
                <div className="category-card">
                    <img src="https://clicon-html.netlify.app/image/product/product-9.png" alt="" className='category-image' />
                    <h6 className="category-text">Computer & Laptop</h6>
                </div>
            </SwiperSlide>
            <SwiperSlide>
                <div className="category-card">
                    <img src="https://clicon-html.netlify.app/image/product/product-14.png" alt="" className='category-image' />
                    <h6 className="category-text">TV & Homes</h6>
                </div>
            </SwiperSlide>
            <SwiperSlide>
                <div className="category-card">
                    <img src="https://clicon-html.netlify.app/image/product/product-12.png" alt="" className='category-image' />
                    <h6 className="category-text">Accessories</h6>
                </div>
            </SwiperSlide>
            <SwiperSlide>
                <div className="category-card">
                    <img src="https://clicon-html.netlify.app/image/product/product-9.png" alt="" className='category-image' />
                    <h6 className="category-text">Computer & Laptop</h6>
                </div>
            </SwiperSlide>
          </Swiper>
          <button className="slick-arrow-carousel button-prev review-swiper-button-prev" >
            <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d="M20.25 12H3.75" stroke="white" strokeWidth="1.5" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round"></path>
                <path d="M10.5 5.25L3.75 12L10.5 18.75" stroke="white" strokeWidth="1.5" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round"></path>
            </svg>
          </button>
          <button className="slick-arrow-carousel button-next review-swiper-button-next" >
              <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  <path d="M3.75 12H20.25" stroke="white" strokeWidth="1.5" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round"></path>
                  <path d="M13.5 5.25L20.25 12L13.5 18.75" stroke="white" strokeWidth="1.5" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round"></path>
              </svg>
          </button>
      </div>
    );
}

export default SwiperCarousel;
```

Also done changes in CSS. You can modify accordingly:-

```
.category-slider {
  width: 90% !important;
  position: relative;
  margin: 80px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.category-slider .swiper {
  padding-right: 14px !important;
}
.category-slider .swiper-slide {
  border: 1px solid;
} 
.slick-arrow-carousel{ 
  position: absolute!important;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%); 
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-width: 48px;
  max-width: 48px;
  min-height: 48px;
  max-height: 48px;
  border-radius: 500px;
  display: flex!important;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: orange;
  z-index: 99999;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.slick-arrow-carousel.swiper-button-disabled {
  background-color: grey;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.slick-arrow-carousel svg path {
  stroke: black;
}
.button-prev{
  left: -55px;     
}
.button-next{
  right: -55px;
}
```

Let me know if it works for you or not.